# weblogic.jdbc.common.internal.RmiDataSource_12212_WLStub cannot be cast to javax.sql.DataSource

Tags: weblogic, datasource, jndi

My app is trying to access DataSource through JNDI on Weblogic(12) Server. The following exception is thrown

weblogic.jdbc.common.internal.RmiDataSource_12212_WLStub cannot be cast to javax.sql.DataSource

Where is this class weblogic.jdbc.common.internal.RmiDataSource_12212_WLStub coming into picture.

Comment: Are you trying to access the datasource from outside WebLogic Server, from a stand alone java application for instance ?

Comment: Yes, and I am using wlthint2client.jar

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From My Oracle Support (Doc ID 2005891.1) Version 12.1.1.0 and later
*The remote datasource lookup over RMI is not supported with any thin client jar file.
The Wlthint3client.jar library does not support remote datasource lookup over RMI as the required stub classes are not bundled with this jar file, and hence the error.
JDBC over RMI is also deprecated in general and it can easily be a significant security vulnerability.
It normally works with the full WLS client jar library. But it is also not recommended  - as this feature is currently deprecated and it might be completely removed in the future release.
Alternatives are to use the JDBC driver if you want to create connections to the database from a remote client, or deploy a local EJB which acquires the connection by doing a local lookup of the datasource.*

Answer (score 1):

The WebLogic full client, wlfullclient.jar, is deprecated as of WebLogic Server 12.1.3 and may be removed in a future release. Oracle recommends using the WebLogic Thin T3 client or other appropriate client depending on your environment. For more information on WebLogic client types.

Reference Link

https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/12213/wls/SACLT/jarbuilder.htm#SACLT240