# java.lang.ClassCastException: weblogic.jdbc.common.internal.RmiDataSource cannot be cast to javax.sql.XADataSource

Tags: java, jdbc, weblogic, jta, distributed-transactions

Driver used in weblogic is `oracle.jdbc.xa.client.OracleXADataSource`, when I'm trying lookup to get the XADataSource it's throwing me the above exception from the code :

```
XADataSource xaDS = (XADataSource)initialContext.lookup(/*some jndi*/);
```

Can someone please explain why this is happening and what needs to be improved to fetch XADataSource from the datasource config in weblogic?

Any other alternatives for the same are appreciated too.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [weblogic.jdbc.common.internal.RmiDataSource\_12212\_WLStub cannot be cast to javax.sql.DataSource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42530162/weblogic-jdbc-common-internal-rmidatasource-12212-wlstub-cannot-be-cast-to-javax)

Comment: No, in my case I'm able to cast it to DataSource object, but not to XADataSource which is what I need.

Comment: An `XADataSource` is not intended to be used directly by user code, it serves as a factory for XA-enabled connections for a transaction manager in your AS. The transaction manager will hand you a normal JDBC `java.sql.Connection`. Trying to obtain an `XADataSource` in code doesn't make much sense.